# How to run specific tests annotated with 'WithTagValuesOf' using SerenityRunner and Gradle

Tags: gradle, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run a specific set of junit tests annotated using 'WithTagValuesOf' provided by the Serenity-BDD framework.

Based on the Serenity tutorial, I could find the same for Maven as :

```
mvn clean verify -Dtags="release:sprint-2"
```

But I am trying to find a similar approach for Gradle. For ex:

```
gradle clean test --tests -Dtags="Test-Type:Smoke" aggregate
```

The above gives me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [tags=Test-Type:Smoke]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Can some one help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer as soon as I posted this question (My bad)

I made a tweak to the solution provided for a similar issue for the JBehave implementation. Thanks to Shawn Boyle for the reference https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thucydides-users/IFwX64zuFSw/vC_43Nl_C84J

Here is the code that I added to my build file.

build.gradle:

```
task copyPropsFile << {
    if(!project.hasProperty('environment')){
        ext.environment = 'dev'
    }

    copy{
        from '../conf/' + environment + '/properties/serenity.properties'
        into projectDir
    }

    if (project.hasProperty('tags')) {
        println "JUnit tags set to: $tags"

        ant.propertyfile(file: "$projectDir/serenity.properties") {
            entry(key: "tags", value: "$tags")
        }
    }
}

// Hook into the gradle processTestResources task to execute the copyPropsFile custom task
processTestResources{
    doFirst{
        copyPropsFile.execute()
    }
}
```

And finally I run my tests using

```
gradle clean test aggregate -Ptags="Test-Type:Smoke"
```